# What is tight bound for this series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

How to find the tight bound for this binomial series
$\binom{n}{1}*1+\binom{n}{2}*2,+\ldots,+ \binom{n}{n/2}*(n/2)$

I have found $n2^n$ by this rule
$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2},+\ldots,+ \binom{n}{n/2}=2^n/2$. So, by multyplying $n/2$ with $2^n/2$ we get $O(n2^n)$. But, I feel that my bound is not tight. Please let me know if other solutions are possible.

Comment: Will it be $[\frac{n}{2}]$ in place of $\frac{n}{2}$? $\frac{n}{2}$ may not be an *integer* in general.

Comment: For $k \geqslant 1$, we have $\binom{n}{k}\cdot k = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: @Roronoa I meant $n/2$ integer. For example if $n=21$, then $n/2=11$. It is ceil function

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, we get (assuming $n$ is even)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}k\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}k\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=n\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\binom{n-1}{j}.
$$
Can you go from here? (A similar case works for $n$ odd)

Comment: Thank you. I am doing further.